# Where are the app cookies stored on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cookies, tracking

When **i don't use a UIWebView (e.g. no WebKit)**, where do the app store the cookies ?
I have the path for cookies created via WebKit ; /var/mobile/Applications/MyApp/Cookies/
but i can't find the path for other cookies

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need this information?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by other cookies? If they are created by something other than MyApp, they are not available within your app's sandbox.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can create cookies via a WebView (using WebKit) or directly via Objective C code.

Comment: #define MARQUAGE_TEST @"http://myurl"
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:MARQUAGE_TEST];
    NSMutableURLRequest *testrequete = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *sendingConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:testrequete delegate:self];
    [sendingConnection start];

Comment: the question is to know weather WebView cookies (where third party cookies are not possible) & cookies directly in the app (outside WebKit, so third party cookies possible) are located in the same directory or in a different directory. I need this info regarding user privacy & mobile tracking